# Automatically mark manually moved unread Outlook email as read?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

When selecting an unread email, right click, Move > Archive folder. What do I need to do within Outlook that once the unread email moves to the folder of **my** selection, it is automatically marked as read?

Outlook will automatically set a deleted email to read, great stuff! If I had rules to move certain emails to a certain folder, again; it can automatically mark that email as read.

I cannot for the life of me find the option to mark an unread email as read when it is manually moved to a folder of my selection.

Any help anyone can be to this I would be greatly appreciative.

Outlook Office 365 I believe is the Outlook this new (to me) company is using.

Comment: ps, the Reading Pane options don't seem to be my friend in this instance...

Comment: To clarify "*Archive folder*" is an arbitrary folder you choose, right? Not the [outlook archive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-in-outlook-for-windows-25f75777-3cdc-4c77-9783-5929c7b47028)?
Also, what research have you done so far? Any websearches you've run on this topic? Please edit your answer to include what you've found so far, this prevents that answerers suggest something you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Rules do have a "mark as read" action that can be applied, but to the best of my knowledge, rules make "active" actions ("move emails with this subject to this folder and mark as read"), they don't detect "passive" actions ("when email goes into this folder, mark as read").

Since this is a manual action not an automatic one you want to do a Quick Action rather than a Rule.

(My instructions and screenshots are from Outlook 2010 as it is what I have available, but I'd be surprised if 365 doesn't have this functionality.)

1. Under the Home ribbon, in the Quick Steps group, click Create New. Or, right click an email and in the context menu, hover Qucik Steps and click Create New.
   [[image]][image]
2. Add two actions to the step, one to move to the folder and the other to set it as read. Make the name self-explanatory and you can also optionally add a description and keyboard shortcut.
   [image]
3. Now you can use your Quick Step by right clicking on your selected email(s).
   [image]